# Jquery processing a string to seperate items like 'value1', 'value2', 'value3' etc

Tags: jquery, string, join, split

I have this jquery script where I get div classes from the page and use them to pre-select checkboxes.

Everything is working except I'm not getting the values in function "className" I need a list like: 'value1', 'value2', 'value3'.

If its only 1 value then I need to get the list: 
'value1'

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this? I searched everywhere for split() and join() examples but couldn't find a solution.

Thank you.

```
                        <script>            
                            (function($) { 
                            $(document).on('facetwp-refresh', function() {

                            if (! FWP.loaded && '' == FWP.build_query_string()  ) { 

                                    //I get list of CSS class names from a specific div holder on the page                      
                                    var classNames = $("#myDiv").attr("class").toString().split('.');
                                    $.each(classNames, function (i, className) {


                                    // Note: Here is where I would like a list like this crated. Basically in "className" value I need: 'running', 'spa', 'swimming-pool' 
                                    FWP.facets['facilities'] = [className]; 
                                    console.log( className );

                // This would be my manual way of me solving this issue but I would like to use a string to get this done cleanly.
                //                  if ( $("#myDiv").hasClass("value1")  ){                     
                //                      FWP.facets['facilities'] = ['value1'];  
                //                      
                //                  }               
                //                  if ( $("#myDiv").hasClass("value1 value2")  ){                      
                //                      FWP.facets['facilities'] = ['value2', 'value1'];    
                //                  }               
                //                  if ( $("#myDiv").hasClass("value2")  ){                     
                //                      FWP.facets['facilities'] = ['value2'];  
                //                  }
                //                  if ( $("#myDiv").hasClass("value1 valueg value3 value4")  ){                        
                //                      FWP.facets['facilities'] = ['value2', 'value1', 'value3', 'value4'];    
                //                  }               
                        });     
                            }       


                            });
                            })(jQuery);
                            </script>
```

Edit 1:

So I am able to get the string in the format I want but it's not selecting the checkboxes.

This is what I've got now...

```
            <script>            
                    (function($) { 

                    $(document).on('facetwp-refresh', function() {

                    if (! FWP.loaded && '' == FWP.build_query_string()  ) { 

                            var classNames = $("#myDiv").attr("class").toString().split(" ").join("', '");

                                FWP.facets['facilities'] = ["'" + classNames + "'"];    
                                console.log( "'" + classNames + "'");   
                    }       


                    });
                    })(jQuery);
        </script>
```

I get this result in console now: 'value1', 'value2', 'value3'

Comment: Have you tried `.split(' ')`?

Comment: "*it's not selecting the checkboxes*" - err - what checkboxes?